# Set matplotlib default figure window title

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

The default window title of a figure is figure X, where X is increased each figure.

I know how to change the title of a figure:

```
fig = pylab.gcf()
fig.canvas.set_window_title('Test')
```

But how do I change the default window title (So that it will be "Test 1", "Test 2" etc.), so that I will not need to change the window title each time?

I did not find a key in the `mpl.rcParams`

Comment: For those of you who came here wanting to change the window title after the figure creation, the above no longer works. You now need to do something like `plt.get_current_fig_manager().set_window_title("My new window title")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no key in `mpl.rcParams` since the default title is hardcoded in the backends. For example, have a look at the [figure initialization code of the QT5 backend](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/c1a3c030c66f512c6f79e4f45b0870b68921320c/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py#L554):

```
self.window.setWindowTitle("Figure %d" % num)
```

This means **you cannot change the default window title** unless you change the code of the matplotlib module itself.

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/8a8dd9093d381500555bccf46fc5d46b42d132ec/lib/matplotlib/backend_bases.py#L2777

Answer (score 13):

***Edit:** my answer does not change the defaults, as requested by OP, but provides a way to define figure title at figure creation.*

When creating a figure using `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`, there is an optional argument `num` that, even if not documented as such (as far as I could search), is later used as figure title:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, num="some nice window title")
plt.ion()  # to make plot non-blocking, i.e. if multiple plots are launched
fig.show()
```

It is also used as default filename when saving the plot, which is a very neat feature.

(Caution: even if not documented, this `num` value is also a key to this figure. So, take care not to reuse the same value.)

And here's the result:
[image]

Comment: It's nice, thanks,  but it is not exactly what I needed. I wanted to change the default behavior.

Comment: There is a comment about the 'num' kwargs in the [matplotlib.pyplot.figure documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html?highlight=figure#matplotlib.pyplot.figure) 3.2.1.   _If not provided, a new figure will be created, and the figure number will be incremented. The figure objects holds this number in a number attribute. If num is provided, and a figure with this id already exists, make it active, and returns a reference to it. If this figure does not exists, create it and returns it. **If num is a string, the window title will be set to this figure's num.**_

Comment: Even if this doesn't answer the OPs question, it seems to be useful because an internet search to the question how to set a specific window title finds this :-)

Comment: @AstroFloyd, and that is how I found it :)

Comment: @Oren You can always define a wrapper around e.g. ```pyplot.subplot()``` to enforce a default behavior that suits you better:

```def my_subplot(plt: matplotlib.pyplot, *args, **kwargs): if not 'num' in kwargs: kwargs['num'] = 'I want it *that* way'; return plt.subplot(*args, **kwargs)```

Maybe you want to define that as a method of a subclass of ```pyplot``` that you use instead.