# How to create an interactive animation in a tkinter GUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, tkinter, charts

I have created a tkinter GUI that when a button is pushed a tk.toplevel is created with an interactive animated chart inside. When I run it for the first time and push the button to create the tk.toplevel with the chart, it works well, but when I close the tk.toplevel and push the button to open a new tk.toplevel, another extra chart appears. Apart from that, If I close the program and I want to run it again I have to close the terminal because it freezes.

I have tried removing `plt.ion()` and doing `plt.show()` but none of these options solve the problem. Also, I have seen the use of multiprocessing, but I don't really understand it well and I don't know why is it needed.

Why does it happen? How can I solve this problem?
Here is the code that I have used:

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.figure as mf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as ani
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import numpy as np

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack()
        frame = MAININTERFACE(parent=container, controller=self)
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    def graph(self):
        grafica1=GRAPHICATION(controller=self)
        grafica1.Graph()

class MAININTERFACE(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.button=tk.Button(self, text='GRAPH', command=lambda: self.controller.graph())
        self.button.pack(pady=20)

class GRAPHICATION(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.controller=controller
        self.x=[]
        self.y=[]
    def animation_frame(self, i):
        if i==0.0:
            self.time=0
            self.energy=0
        else:
            self.time=self.time+1
            self.energy=self.energy+1
        self.x.append(self.time)
        self.y.append(self.energy)
        self.line.set_data(self.x,self.y)
        self.ax.axis([0,10,0,10])

    def Graph(self):
        self.graphtoplevel=tk.Toplevel(self.controller)
        self.graphtoplevel.title('Toplevel')
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.graph=FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self.graphtoplevel)
        self.image=self.graph.get_tk_widget()
        plt.ion()
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(self.x,self.y)
        self.image.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.animation=FuncAnimation(self.fig,func=self.animation_frame,frames=np.arange(0,11,1),interval=500, repeat=False)
        self.snap_cursor = SnaptoCursor(self.ax, self.x, self.y)
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.snap_cursor.mouse_click)

class SnaptoCursor(object):
    """
    Like Cursor but the crosshair snaps to the nearest x, y point.
    For simplicity, this assumes that *x* is sorted.
    """

    def __init__(self, ax, x, y):
        self.ax = ax
        self.lx = ax.axhline(color='k', linewidth=0.5)  # the horiz line
        self.ly = ax.axvline(color='k', linewidth=0.5)  # the vert line
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        # text location in axes coords
        self.txt = ax.text(0.05, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)

    def mouse_click(self, event):
        if not event.inaxes:
            return

        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
        indx = min(np.searchsorted(self.x, x), len(self.x) - 1)
        x = self.x[indx]
        y = self.y[indx]
        # update the line positions
        self.lx.set_ydata(y)
        self.ly.set_xdata(x)

        self.txt.set_text('x=%1.2f, y=%1.2f' % (x, y))
        self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.geometry('500x200')
    app.title('MAIN GUI')
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: It works well for me on Windows 10, Python 3.9

Comment: I use the same. Have you tried this @Mandera: first; close the tk.toplevel and open a new one (If I do that a new figure is generated apart from the tk.toplevel); Second, close the main interface and run the program again (It freezes and I need to kill terminal to run it again).

Comment: One tk window opens each time I press the button, I can close them without a problem. I can also close and run the program repeatedly without a problem. Might be because of the IDE? I'm using PyCharm

Comment: Okey, I'm using Visual Studio Code, maybe it's that the issue.@Mandera

Comment: Alright, could be! PyCharm is great, it's worth a try

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes to your def Graph(self) function, as there are lines that are creating a window with tk.Toplevel and then the plt is creating another window.

Make your changes as follows, the capitalized comments you must do, and the others are optional for setting of titles:

```
    def Graph(self):
        #REMOVE THESE LINES
        #self.graphtoplevel=tk.Toplevel(self.controller)
        #self.graphtoplevel.title('Toplevel')

        #modify the window title to your liking by assigning num
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(num="TopLevel")

        #REMOVE THESE LINES
        #self.graph=FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self.graphtoplevel)
        #self.image=self.graph.get_tk_widget()

        plt.ion()
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(self.x,self.y)

        #REMOVE THIS LINE
        #self.image.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        
        self.animation=FuncAnimation(self.fig,func=self.animation_frame,frames=np.arange(0,11,1),interval=500, repeat=False)
        self.snap_cursor = SnaptoCursor(self.ax, self.x, self.y)
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.snap_cursor.mouse_click)

        # displaying a title on top of figure (or do not add if not needed)
        plt.title("Specific Fig Desc Title")

        #ADD THIS LINE TO SHOW WINDOW
        plt.show()
```

Please see this for more on figure window title:

[Set matplotlib default figure window title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307438/set-matplotlib-default-figure-window-title)

Comment: Thank you, that's useful if I don't need the tk.Toplevel. In my case, I want to maintain it because I want to add some other widgets to the window. The final result should be an interactive animated graph inside a tk.Toplevel.